# Solve a a system of first order differential equations with a vector constant $\vec{x}' = A\vec{x}+\vec{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a modeling initial value problem actually but I'm just asking about this part. I already have the correct system to model the situation.

$\vec{x}'= \begin{bmatrix}-1/50 & 1/100\\1/100 & -1/50\end{bmatrix}\vec{x} + \begin{bmatrix}7\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

$\vec{x}(0)= \begin{bmatrix}30\\0\end{bmatrix}$

The last vector is a constant, so I *can't* treat this as $x' = Ax + g(t)$.

I've already solved for the "homogeneous" solution and the respective eigenvalues/vectors, if that's a good place to start:

$\vec{x}_c(t) = c_1e^{-3t/100}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix} + c_2e^{-t/100}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Might someone point me to the next step in the process?
Thanks.

Comment: Find a constant vector $\vec x_0$ such that $(\vec x_0'=)\quad 0=A\vec x_0+\vec b$. The general integral will be $\vec x_c(t)+\vec x_0$.

Comment: I tried putting that into my initial condition to solve the eventual initial value problem, but I didn't get the right answer. I'll double check my $\vec{x}_0$ again

Comment: I do not understand why you can't use undetermined coefficients or variation of parameters to find the solution. You will just have $c_1$ and $c_2$ as you did not specify ICs, but can still find the particular solution without those and write the solution.

Comment: I tried both methods and got what is apparently the wrong answer both times.

Answer (score 0):

@G. Sassatelli Aah yes someone told me to do this but I tried to add it to the end of the complementary solution but I don't think that's right.

Either way for $\vec{x}_0$ I got $\begin{bmatrix}1400/3\\ 700/3\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I ended up with $C_1 \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}+C_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1310/3\\-700/3\end{bmatrix}$ and solved for $C_1$ and $C_2$, finding $\begin{bmatrix}305/3\\-335\end{bmatrix}$ but this was not the correct answer?

Comment: Oh, these values were correct, and so was the particular solution! I just forgot to bring in the particular solution when formulating the final answer. Doy!

Answer (score 0):

$\dot{x}=Ax(t)+b$

multiplying both sides by $e^{-At}$ we get
$e^{-At}\dot{x}=e^{-At}Ax(t)+e^{-At}b$

$e^{-At}\dot{x}-e^{-At}Ax(t)=e^{-At}b$    which can be written as

$\frac{{\rm d}(e^{-At}x(t))}{{\rm d}t}=e^{-At}b$

$\int_0^t(\frac{{\rm d}(e^{-At}x(t))}{{\rm d}t}){\rm d}\tau=\int_0^t(e^{-At}b){\rm d}\tau$
integrating and rearranging, we get the solution as

$x(t)=e^{At}x(0)+\int_0^t e^{(A(t-\tau))}b~{\rm d}\tau$

Hope this helps

Comment: Integrating form $0$ to $\infty$ is wrong (and it does not yield the results you claim). Moreover, you are integrating in $\mathrm d\tau$ stuff that is constant with respect to $\tau$. With everything correctly set up, i.e. $$\int_0^t \frac{d(\exp(-A\tau)x(\tau))}{d\tau}\,d\tau=\int_0^t \exp(-A\tau)b\,d\tau$$ what we get is $$x(t)=\exp(At) x_0+\int_0^t\exp(A(t-\tau))b\,d\tau\\= \exp(At) x_0-A^{-1}\exp(A(t-t))b+A^{-1}\exp(A(t-0))b\\ = \exp(At) (x_0+A^{-1}b)-A^{-1}b$$

Comment: I don't know what $e^{-At}$ means.

Comment: Sorry, @  G Sassatelli, You are right, Thank you. @J.S.R to calculate $e^{-At}$, if you are familiar with Laplace transform you may use, Laplace inverse such as  $e^{-At}=L^{-1}\{(SI-A)^{-1}\}$, where $I$ is an $n x n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Oh! My professor did not go over such things with us. Although I have an update: after getting the correct $c_1$ and $c_2$ values, I forgot to add in the particular solution when forming the final $x(t)$. So that is how I got things wrong several times over. I was stumped for days :D